# How to animate a background image to move behind text?

Tags: css

I'm working on a dummy website for a portfolio.

So far, it looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/yr1lDX7]

What I want to do is make the blue sky image constantly scroll to the right, so it looks like the clouds are moving within the title text.

Here is the CSS I have for the text right now:

```
#site-title {
font-size: 20em;
background: url('../../img/colors.jpg') no-repeat bottom center;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Is it possible to make the cloud background move infinitely to the right without affecting the text?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Are you looking at this http://jsfiddle.net/YSYRe/24/

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyframes to accomplish this effect.

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

#animate-area   { 
    width: 560px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-image: url(bg-clouds.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

See the [code example and demo here](http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css).

Comment: That looks like it would work perfectly, but I can't get it to work with my code.

Comment: if you post your code or perhaps a http://jsfiddle.net/ I could try and help out.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I fixed it. I stupidly forgot the vendor prefixes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.text { 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   background-image: url(yourimage.jpg);
   background-size: 300% 300% !important;
   -webkit-animation: Gradient 10s ease-in-out infinite;
   -moz-animation: Gradient 10s ease-in-out infinite;
   animation: Gradient 10s ease-in-out infinite;
   margin:15px 0;
   font-size: 45px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
     0% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
     50% {
         background-position: 100% 50% 
    }
     100% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes Gradient {
     0% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
     50% {
         background-position: 100% 50% 
    }
     100% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
}
 @keyframes Gradient {
     0% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
     50% {
         background-position: 100% 50% 
    }
     100% {
         background-position: 0% 50% 
    }
}
```